# prepros live preview + xampp vhost > error 500

Tags: xampp, prepros, live-preview

I just installed prepros, because I like this idea. I'm already using xampp vhost for developing websites. But i'm getting error 500 from prepros. 
my setup:
[httpd-vhosts.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F1kn.png)
[prepros setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8wfY.png)
and result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnsBB.png)

I'll be happy, if anybody will help me :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please insert your images and code snippets in your post and don't use links to external sites. 
What did you try? Please describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Those external links was inserted by stack overflow. I believed that is the right way. Please check them. I didn't try anything else, because I don't understand proxy settings. Thanks.